# Managed Properties: can they be mapped at list level

Tags: list, managed-property

Afternoon all,

Can anyone advise if it's possible to map a managed property to a column that exists within a custom list (read: not a Site Column or part of a list template).

I've indexed the columns that I want to map via a full crawl and want to set them up for use within a customised search form.  I do believe it's possible but would like to be sure.

Many thanks,
Steven